# Login a user with their firebase user id react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

so I wanted to keep a user logged in after they reload the app. I did that by using
`Async Storage`, What I did was if a user's id is present in the Async Storage, I would consider them logged in. The drawback was I couldn't use the `Firebase auth` because it wont consider the user logged in. I know that it's a bad idea to store passwords in Async Storage so i stored the uid. Is there any way I could log in they user with just their uid so if i use `firebase.currentUser` it won't show null.

I am using firebase v9 and react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the web version of firebase. You have to consider using the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) library which handles this behavior automatically for free.

And the answer to your question. No, you can't log the user in using his `uid`.

Comment: Help me i cant setup react-native-firebase with expo its confusing

Comment: You can follow this documentation to setup firebase in an Expo project: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/setup-native-firebase/